# Replace semicolon(;) with comma(,) in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

How to replace semicolon (`;`) with comma (`,`) in a stored procedure?

I am using SQL Server, I am trying to insert data from a `.csv` file. Data is inserted successfully but one column contains semicolon (`;`) in value.

My requirement is to replace that semicolon with a comma while inserting into the database.

I am new to stored procedure. If anyone knows, please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that two columns are being imported as one because you have mixed delimiters within the file?

Comment: Please post an example of what this file looks like with this semicolon in the value. If you have a CSV file that uses semicolon as delimiters, and you're not quoting the values (adding quotes around them), you *cannot* have semicolons in the values, this will basically not work.

Comment: If there's some reason you can't simply use the Replace function after doing the import, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this way you can replace,

```
SELECT REPLACE(FieldName ,';',',') FROM TableName
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO TableName (FieldName) VALUES (REPLACE(FieldValue,'.',';'))
```